# How to initialize a scoped injected class in ASP.NET Core involving asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I need to initialize an injected class at the scope level in ASP.NET Core - the initialization involves asynchronous method calls.  You wouldn't do this in the constructor, nor a property accessor.

A common DI use in an asp.net core application is getting the current user. I implemented this by creating an `IUserContext` abstraction and injecting it at the scoped level:

```
public sealed class AspNetUserContext : IUserContext
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    private User currentUser;

    public AspNetUserContext(IHttpContextAccessor a, UserManager<User> userManager) {
        accessor = a;

        if (userManager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userManager");

        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public string Name => accessor.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;
    public int Id => accessor.CurrentUserId();

    public User CurrentUser {
        get {
            if (currentUser == null) {
                currentUser = this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(Id.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

            return currentUser;
        }
    }
}
```

I am struggling trying to find out how to correctly initialize the `CurrentUser` property.

Since there is no longer any way to get a user from the `UserManager` class sychronously, I am not comfortable running an async method from within a property getter when initializing the `CurrentUser`, nor from the constructor (there are no long any synchronous methods on the `UserManager` class with ASP.NET Core).

I feel like the correct way to do this would be to run an initialization method on the injected instance somehow once per request since it is scoped (perhaps with an action filter/middleware/Controller base class (or perhaps in the dependency injection `AddScoped` method itself as a factory method?)

This seems like a pretty common problem and I'm wondering how others have resolved this.

Comment: The current user is a property on the `Context` -> if you're using the .Net core auth/approach, which is what I would recommend. It's set automatically if you're using cookie or token auth

Comment: Yes you can see that I use the HttpContext to get the name of the user.  However, the full user object is not present in the context (you can only retrieve claims or the name of the user that way).  You can only get the full user object by caling UserManger.FindByIdAsync, or using EFCore directly.

Comment: If you need to load the user, then load the user. It is not an injectable dependency... I would offer that the user prinicpal object is flexible enough to be able to contain just about whatever you *should* need - if you need to go beyond this, then maybe there's a higher-level design problem

Comment: I want to load the user via dependency injection so I can unit test.  Because UserManager no longer has synchronous methods to load it, it presents a problem.  Do you load the user in a constructor of an injected service, or as a property?  Or would you initialize it from an action filter or middleware?  That was my question.

Comment: You would mock the user manager and/or divide your program into smaller pieces. Also, any async method can be run synchronously.

Comment: If I mock the UserManager, that means calling FindByIdAsync repeatedly in each class or service that needs it per session.  I'd prefer to look it up once.

Yes, if you look at my source code, you will see I am running the asynchronous method FindByIdAsync synchronously using GetAwaiter.  The issue with that is deadlocks and it running under a different context when ConfigureAwait is ran.

Comment: What do you mean "each class or service that needs it per session?" I think you may have an x-y problem here. Your question needs to be "how do I populate additional parameters on my `Context.User`" - I'm sure you'll find there are many ways to do this such that it only needs to be called in one place. As to the deadlock, I think you should post a secondary question if you can't sort that out.

Comment: I’m not sure how much clearer I can be here.  You are suggesting that, instead of injecting a class that has the current user already populated, to instead use UserManager.FindByIdAsync in every class that I want to access the current user (else why mock it?)  my question is very specific - how do I initialize an injected class in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 4):

In this case you will need to forgo the property and have an asynchronous method.

This would also mean having an asynchronous lazy initialization for the User using

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides support for asynchronous lazy initialization.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class LazyAsync<T> : Lazy<Task<T>> {
    /// <summary>
    ///  Initializes a new instance of the LazyAsync`1 class. When lazy initialization
    ///  occurs, the specified initialization function is used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="valueFactory">The delegate that is invoked to produce the lazily initialized Task when it is needed.</param>
    public LazyAsync(Func<Task<T>> valueFactory) :
        base(() => Task.Run(valueFactory)) { }
}
```

This now makes it possible to refactor the context to use lazy initialization,

```
public sealed class AspNetUserContext : IUserContext {
    private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    private readonly LazyAsync<User> currentUser;

    public AspNetUserContext(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, UserManager<User> userManager) {
        this.accessor = accessor;

        if (userManager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));

        this.userManager = userManager;

        currentUser = new LazyAsync<User>(() => this.userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id.ToString()));
    }

    public string Name => accessor.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;
    public int Id => accessor.CurrentUserId();

    public Task<User> GetCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser.Value;
    }
}
```

And used where needed

```
User user = await context.GetCurrentUser();
```

Now a property **could** have still been used like

```
public Task<User> CurrentUser => currentUser.Value;
```

as the getter is a method, but that is not a very intuitive design in my personal opinion.

```
User user = await context.CurrentUser;
```

and can have undesirable results if accessed too early.

I only mention it because of the design of the original context shown in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following,

1) Register IUserContext and UserContext as Scoped

2) Retrieve IUSerContext or UserContext via httpContext,

```
IUserContext userContext = (IUserContext)httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IUserContext));
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach is a little bit different from [nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi)'s answer.

Your final requirement is to access one or more `User` property, right?

So, you can take advantange by using delegates mixed with async:

```
public interface IUserAccessor
{
    Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(Func<User, TValue> func);
}

public class UserAccessor
{
    public UserAccessor(MyDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    private readonly MyDbContext db;

    public async Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(Func<User, TValue> func)
    {
        return func(await this.db.FindUsersBySomeConditions().FirstOrDefaultAsync());
    }
}
```

If your service is scoped, you can also use a persistence and avoid a second call to DB:

```
private User user;

public async Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(Func<User, TValue> func)
{
    if (this.user == null)
    {
        this.user = await this.db.FindUsersBySomeConditions().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    return func(this.user);
}
```

You can use like this:

```
@inject IUserService userService

// ...

<div>
    <div>@await userService.GetValueAsync(u => u.Name)</div>
    <div>@await userService.GetValueAsync(u => u.Role)</div>
    <div>@await userService.GetValueAsync(u => u.BirthDate)</div>
    <div>@await userService.GetValueAsync(u => u.ComplexProperty.SubProperty)</div>
</div>
```